# git tag fails with $'\226git': command not found

Tags: git-bash, git-tag

I'm using Git BASH in windows 7 and I try to create a tag:

```
git tag -a v2.44.13 -m "[before prod] bla bla bla"
```

and fails with:

```
$'\226git': command not found
```

Same command works with Git CMD. Why this happens and how to solve it?

*git version 2.11.0.windows.1*

Comment: I’ve only seen this happen when copying rich text into a terminal. Have you ruled out copy-paste errors by typing in the command by hand?

Comment: I only typed the command.

Comment: In that case, you have an alias set, possibly in the git-bash dotfile, that’s referring to ‘\226git’.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I have faced same issue and it was because of copy-paste. Typing by hand solves the issue. If you don't want type all the command by hand try to go at the starting of the command after pasting it to the console and click backspace button multiple times. This should remove hidden characters and should work also.

Comment: I already pointed above that I only typed the command (so no copy-paste).

Comment: cherry-pick wihtout copy paste technology is a hell!

Answer (score 16):

When you type `Ctrl+Shift+V` in the terminal it adds the `\226` code to the command line. If you type `Shift+Insert` without attempting any keyboard shortcuts it should work properly.

Comment: This is closer to the correct answer as to why.  For me I get it even when I shfit-Insert. And I get `$'\302\203`. Is this a Windows thing - I'm currently (forced to use) Windows 10 - so this bug has been around for some time in some form?  i thought Windows was trying to become more dev friendly.

Comment: Right. `Ctrl+Shift+V` in git-bash terminal added `\302\226ssh` for me. Logically, `command not found`. Typing command or right click pasting works.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you remove any character before your command

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same problem when I haven't selected vim as the default editor in git.

In my case problem gets resolved by using a space before writing any command.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use `Ctrl + Insert` to copy and `Shift + Insert` to paste.

Answer (score 0):

Copy Paste issue...

"\302\203": copy-to-clipboard
"\302\226": paste-from-clipboard

This worked for me :
Add the following line to your ~/.bashrc:

```
stty lnext ^q stop undef start undef
```

And add the following line to your ~/.inputrc:

```
"\C-v": paste-from-clipboard
```

https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/05/how-to-paste-in-cygwin-bash-using-ctrl/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).